# ASP.NET WebForms: Why can't I download certain files that I've uploaded through my application?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a simple `asp:FileUpload` control that saves a file to the server.  It saves the file to disk then creates a path reference to it in the database.  We display these files in a DataGrid using this markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href='<%# MyApp.Global_asax.UploadPath + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FolderName") + "/" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>' target="_blank">
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>
    </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So, as you can see, it's nothing special.  However, trying to download some files results in this message in IE9:

```
The page cannot be found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I get a similar message in FireFox.

So far, this is happening only with `.DOTM` files.  I thought it could be the file name, so I changed the name to something simple like `xxx.dotm`, but this still doesn't download.  When I change the extension to `TXT` so it's `xxx.txt`, though, I am able to download the file just fine.

Is anyone able to give me an idea as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the MIME type in IIS for that file extension.

For IIS 6.0:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

For IIS 7.0:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Perfect!  I added the dotm extension per the IIS 6.9 instructions and it's working fine.